# Dev_appserver.py error when trying to deploy to Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dart

I'm trying to deploy an example dart server using Google AppEngine.  However when I run this python script (with the latest python version installed 3.5)

> dev_appserver.py

I've also tried

> dev_appserver.py --custom_entrypoint "dart bin/server.dart {port}" app.yaml

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jkrie\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud- sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py", line 11, in <module>
    import bootstrapping.bootstrapping as bootstrapping
  File "C:\Users\jkrie\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 9, in <module>
    import setup
```

> ImportError: No module named 'setup'

I've also installed setuptools.  I have to assume there is something wrong with my Google Cloud SDK install, but I really don't know what.  Is python 3.5 too new and I need to try an older version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GAE [standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment) only supports Python 2.7 at this time, see [Google App Engine Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs).

Python 3.4 is supported only in the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/), which has [a different development flow](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app).

Related: [Google cloud dev_appserver.py unable to host laravel project locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132686/google-cloud-dev-appserver-py-unable-to-host-laravel-project-locally/45865803#45865803)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you have to use Python 2 for the standard App Engine environment for the time being.

If you have Python 3 installed, you can create a virtualenv using Python 2 using `mkvirtualenv google --python=$(which python2)` and run `dev_appserver.py .` in that environment.

This saves you the hassle of having to downgrade or symlink python to python2

Answer (score 4):

Google could prepend the file with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

It would make their tools compatible with OSs that use python3 as default.

Answer (score 2):

As @dan-cornilescu said GAE Standard Environment support only Python2.7

If you are in an environment with multiversion of Python, you could easly use [Pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) to run your dev_appserver.py with Python 2.7 version.

After you [have installed pipenv globaly](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv#installation) you could create a pipenv environment inside your project folder with Python 2.7

```
# pipenv install --twoo
```

Every time you need to run dev_appserver.py you should use this command

```
# pipenv run dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

pipenv will use Python 2.7 to run your code. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue since I install both python2.9 and python3.6.
Quick way without uninstall python3 is just delete python3 path in environment variables while you are using GAE. Add them back when done with GAE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a very simple python35 app (now, a year later!) 
I did create a python27 virtual environment which does work, but needed more workarounds.

The easiest thing is to just run `python applicationmodule.py` on the shell command line, ensuring you have this at the bottom:
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)`

If you want to run using `dev_appserver.py` then, I found I needed to run the following to make this work on the Google Cloud Shell:`dev_appserver.py app.yaml --custom_entrypoint ./applicationmodule.py`

In that case, make sure the `applicationmodule.py` doesn't have the `if __name__ == '__main__':` code. If you do have this, then it starts the same task again and complains about contention on port 8080.

This is different from other answers which have the `--custom_entrypoint` parameter looking more like the app.yaml `entrypoint:` entry.

At one point executing *dev_appserver.py* complained about executing *applicationmodule.py* (I forget exactly), so I did both `chmod 777` and I added a `#!` pointing to my local python executable - it worked after having done both, but don't know if it was the `chmod` or the `#!` that did it.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine now supports Python 3 from version 3.7.

If you still have Python 2 as the default, one way to specify version 3 is to add this to your `~/.zshrc` or other startup scripts:

```
CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3
```

The environment variable can also take the full path to the preferred Python executable if it's not aliased to `python3`.

Here's a [quick start guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) and some [differences](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences) between the support for versions 2.7 and 3.7.