# ImportError: No module named 'setup'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using the Google App Engine, and I want to deploy my app to localhost using dev_appserver.py, however when I do that it specifies that some file called "bootstrapping.py" is trying to import 'setup', and that there is no module with that name. I have python3.5 installed. I also have the google-cloud-sdk\bin saved to Path in my environment variables. Did I not install something I should have?

Comment: Is your app a standard or flexible environment one? FWIW the standard environment only supports python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dev\_appserver.py error when trying to deploy to Google AppEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840809/dev-appserver-py-error-when-trying-to-deploy-to-google-appengine)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but was able to fix it by switching to Python 2.7.

I'm using Conda, which has a good guide for creating a Python 2.7 environment while still being able to switch easily back to Python 3.5: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

If you're not using Conda I'm sure there's still a way to switch back to Python 2.7, but I'm not sure if that means you have to get rid of Python 3.5. In any case, switching to 2.7 fixed my problem right away.

Comment: This does work. The Google App Engine also states that they only support Python 2.7, so there are obviously compatibility issues if you use 3

Comment: Yes. I also had same. after switching back to 2.7. It works fine.