# Google App Engine: No module named setup

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-sdk, dev-appserver

I am new to GAE and while doing a course, I needed to install it on my system. I followed the instructions on the GAE website, and it successfully installed on my Ubuntu 17.04 system. Now, I created a folder with the name `first-app` with the files `first-app.py` and `app.yaml`.

Whenever I try to run `dev_appserver.py first-app`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 11, in <module>
    import bootstrapping.bootstrapping as bootstrapping
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 9, in <module>
    import setup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setup'
```

I have both python 2.7 and python 3.5 installed and the default python is 2.7.13.

Below is the content of `first-app.py`:

```
import webapp2

class Mainpage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Hello World")

app=webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Mainpage), ], debug=True)
```

and the content of `app.yaml` file is:

```
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: first-app.app

- url: /index\.html
  script: home.app
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: could you please put the app.yaml here

Comment: I have already put up the contents of app.yaml in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you're somehow ending up running it with python 3, see:

- [ImportError: No module named 'setup'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679482/importerror-no-module-named-setup)
- [Dev_appserver.py error when trying to deploy to Google AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840809/dev-appserver-py-error-when-trying-to-deploy-to-google-appengine)

In addition to trying the answers to those questions I'm thinking you could also try explicitly selecting the python version, like this:

```
python2.7 /usr/bin/dev_appserver.py [first-app ...]
```

A more "permanent" alternative which wouldn't require you to do the above for every invocation would be to modify (as root) `/usr/bin/dev_appserver.py` and replace `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top with `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`. With this change it should just work normally as long as you have a valid 2.7 python installation on your system, even if it's not the default one.

It may appear hacky, but given that `dev_appserver.py` can only be used with standard env GAE apps, which only supports python 2.7, IMHO it's rather natural - Google could have done it in this particular case. But since they didn't, just re-member to re-do it when needed as SDK updates will probably wipe it away.

Comment: Wow! That just worked and now the server is running at http://localhost:8000. But now the new problem is when I open this link in the browser, it redirects to [link](http://localhost:8000/instances) which opens up a google app engine page which shows the instances.

Comment: My bad! I was opening the admin server. It is working fine now. But I wanted to know whether I will need to type python2.7 everytime?